# Elevating IIS worker identity to access Memory Mapped File

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

I need to access a memory mapped file from one of my routes in my Web API. Using the normal IIS worker settings I have no luck and my service always returns "File not found". I tried to add the prefix "Global/" but still no luck.

After reading many hours on the web I learned that I need to change the Identity of the IIS worker. So, just for testing purposes I changed the worker identity to the Administrator account. I uploaded a picture here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHoKQ.jpg

But still no luck. Does anyone here know how to configure IIS correctly?

Here is how I access the Memory Mapped File using c#:

```
string Message = "";

try
{
    string MMF_In_Name = "Global\\MMF_Name";
    MemoryMappedFile MMF_In = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(MMF_In_Name);

    Messages.Add("Connected to MMF");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Messages.Add(ex.Message);
}
```

I have double checked the name of the memory mapped file and it's correct. A command line tool run as Administrator works as expected.

I'm using IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: As far as Windows is concerned, an IIS worker process is identical to any other process, and it has all the access rights of the user account it's running as. Are you sure the code is correct? Can you successfully open the file if f.e. you run the same code in a standard process?

Comment: Yes, I can successfully use the Memory Mapped File. On another thread someone told me that I need to create the file with the prefix "Global/". I'll try that as well.

Comment: This *COULD* be yet another UAC issue (although it should then affect a standard process in the same way as an IIS process). Can you try turning UAC off?

Answer (score 0):

This works on Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8.5.

It's important to understand that the IIS worker runs in a different Terminal Server Session than normal applications. Much like a Windows Service.

So when the application exposing a Memory Mapped File it needs create it via the "Global\" prefix added to the name. But it also needs add a security descriptor or identity. In c# it would look like this:

```
string MMF_Name = @"Global\MyMemoryMappedFileName";

var security = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
security.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null)
    , MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl
    , AccessControlType.Allow)
    );


var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(MMF_Name
    , 1024 * 1024
    , MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite
    , MemoryMappedFileOptions.None
    , security
    , System.IO.HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
```

In C++ it would look like this:

```
TCHAR szName[] = TEXT("Global\MyMemoryMappedFileName");

HANDLE hMapFile;
LPCTSTR pBuf;

SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;

if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
  printf("InitializeSecurityDescriptor failed %d\n", GetLastError());

if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, true, 0, false))
  printf("SetSecurityDescriptorDacl failed %d\n", GetLastError());

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;
sa.bInheritHandle = false;



hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
  INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
  &sa,                    // default security
  PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
  0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
  BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
  szName);                 // name of mapping object

if (hMapFile == NULL)
{
  _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),
       GetLastError());
  return 1;
}
```

An application creating such objects needs to start with Admin rights.

Now when a client like the IIS worker tries to access the file it needs to make sure to use the correct name, aka use the "Global\" prefix. In C# it would look like:

```
string MMF_Name = @"Global\MyMemoryMappedFileName";

var MMF = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(MMF_Name
    , MemoryMappedFileRights.ReadWrite
    , HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
```

In C++:

```
TCHAR szName[] = TEXT("Global\\MyMemoryMappedFileName");

HANDLE hMapFile;
LPCTSTR pBuf;

hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(
  FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,   // read/write access
  TRUE,                 // !!!!! do inherit the name
  szName);               // name of mapping object

if (hMapFile == NULL)
{
  _tprintf(TEXT("Could not open file mapping object (%d).\n"),
       GetLastError());
  return 1;
}
```

When all this is done. The IIS worker should be able to access the application via the memory mapped file. No need to change the identity of the worker. In fact, I run it in default settings.